# Using drush to install multiple sites, how?

Tags: drush, multi-sites, installation

I'm executing the following commands in /var/www/html on a clean Ubuntu 14.04 installation:

```
drush dl --drupal-project-rename=Platform
cd Platform
drush site install standard -y --db-url=[mysql connection string]/drupal --site-name=Example1
```

This sets up the site and it's awesome (especially after fighting for two days with the web interface and silly errors).

But now I want to install a 2nd site on this installation:

```
drush site install standard -y --db-url=[mysql connection string]/drupal2 --site-name=Example2
```

I get an exception that says, "To start over, you must empty you existing database. To install to a different database, edit the appropriate settings.php file in the sites folder. To upgrade an existing installation etc. etc.".

Is it still trying to install to the original database, thus the reason why I'm getting this error? I created drupal2 prior to running this command, so there's an empty database that exists.

How would I go about fixing this error?

Is it possible to use 1 database for all sites with crush?

Note: Creating a subdirectory in sites and using the --sites-subdir option in the site install command seems to have worked. Not sure how to point my browser to the site or how to use one database yet, but baby steps!

Comment: If you need to share users and contents between multiple sites, use the domain access module (http://drupal.org/project/domain).  Otherwise, you should keep your sites separate.  Avoid multisite in any event, and maintain a separate Drupal root for every site. This will make upgrades easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use 'drush site-install' to install a multisite with separate databases using a single command?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209373/how-do-you-use-drush-site-install-to-install-a-multisite-with-separate-databas)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 1 DB for multiple sites you should get https://www.drupal.org/project/domain. I haven't tried it yet, looks complicated to set up, so good luck =)

For pointing your site, this video might help, skip to 15:49 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea_Tqd-NrC4 It doesn't cover diff root directories for diff domains tho.

Comment: FYI: just recently I learned a little trick to point right away to the right spot, such as to https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea_Tqd-NrC4&t=15m49s ... Forgot which user here on drupal.SE used such extra URL argument here on drupal.SE ...