# How do you use 'drush site-install' to install a multisite with separate databases using a single command?

Tags: 8, database, drush, multi-sites, installation

I regularly use `drush site-install` to install single Drupal 8 sites from the command line. It works great.

I'm now working on building a Drupal 8 multisite. It'll have separate databases per site.

Can `drush si` be used to install a multisite from the command line? Does it use Drupal8's sites.php?

I saw [Need Steps to Install multisite configuration using only drush. i.e multi-site install having different database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190051/need-steps-to-install-multisite-configuration-using-only-drush-i-e-multi-site-i), but I'm not clear on what's actually done there.

I figured it should be able to, but I can't find any HowTo docs for multisite.

Comment: Did you check https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/site-install/?

Comment: Where on that page does is say anything about multisite installation?
- Gil

Comment: You can specify the `--sites-subdir` which will create a separate folder for multi site

Comment: Which is mentioned in the link I already provided, said I read, and questioned further.  If you have a concrete example, great.  Just saying "look over there somewhere" doesn't help.

Comment: I am not making fun, I just want to ensure how much you know and how further I can provide. No offence.

Comment: I posted the answer, please check it. Let me know if you need something further.

Answer (score 5):

In the link you provided, @greg_1_anderson mentioned using `--sites-subdir`. This option is used to create a site folder under `<DRUPAL_ROOT>/sites/`.

For example, if you run `drush si --sites-subdir=example1.com`, it will create a example1.com folder under `<DRUPAL_ROOT>/sites/`, settings.php will also be generated in this folder. It contains the database configuration.

Since it is a multi site structure, you may not want to share the same database. You have to specify the database information with `--db-url`.

For example:

- DB: MySQL
- root username: username
- root password: password
- host: localhost
- table name: `example`

You can specify above information with `--db-url=mysql://username:password@localhost/example`.

A more complex example involving setting more sites for a multi-site configuration could be the following.

```sh
drush si --sites-subdir=example1.com --url=mysql://username:password@localhost/example1
drush si --sites-subdir=example2.com --url=mysql://username:password@localhost/example2
```

Moreover, if you want to have different database credentials for different sites, you can dynamically create the separate username and password at the same time.

```sh
drush si --sites-subdir=example1.com --url=mysql://user1:newpassword1@localhost/example1 --db-su=username --db-su-pw=password
drush si --sites-subdir=example2.com --url=mysql://user2@newpassword2@localhost/example2 --db-su=username --db-su-pw=password
```

Comment: Splitting hairs, since the OP wants to enter a single line, just put the commands in a single line, separating them with `;` or `&&`.